# Spring junit test template might not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

First of all, the application is successfully compiling and running.

I try to unit test my controllers in spring boot. my test-controller looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Application.class })
@Rollback
@Transactional
@WebMvcTest(PasswordResetController.class)
public class PasswordResetControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void getPasswordForgetView() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(get("/password/forget"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

with this i get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "password-forget-html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

if I debug the configuration, I see that it goes trough my `WebMvcConfig.class` in there I point the templates to the `/WEB-INF/templates/` folder:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.tmp" })
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${mail.templates.cacheable}")
    private boolean mailTemplatesCacheable;

    @Value("${html.templates.cacheable}")
    private boolean htmlTemplatesCacheable;

    public static final String URL_RESOURCES = "/modules/**";
    public static final String PATH_RESOURCES = "/modules/";

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(URL_RESOURCES).addResourceLocations(PATH_RESOURCES);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(htmlTemplatesCacheable);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateResolver mailResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver result = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        result.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/mail/");
        result.setSuffix(".html");
        result.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        result.setCacheable(mailTemplatesCacheable);
        result.setOrder(2);
        result.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(mailResolver());
        templateEngine.addDialect("java8time", java8TimeDialect());
        templateEngine.addDialect("sec", springSecurityDialect());
        templateEngine.addDialect("layout", thymeleafLayoutDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        thymeleafViewResolver.setCache(false);
        return thymeleafViewResolver;
    }

    // Dialect Beans
    ...
}
```

And yes, there are templates in the folder.

Any suggestions? Thank's in advance

Comment: It looks like `WebMvcConfig` out of context for tests. try to add `WebMvcConfig` into `@ContextConfiguration` directly.

Comment: If I debug it, it go trough the WebMvcConfig class

Comment: Is `/WEB-INF/templates/` visible in classpath?

Comment: I think so, because the application is running. It's only about the test cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comment from @eis I got the solution. the annotations `WebMvcTest` and `ContextConfiguration` are contradicting each other. I change the class to the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class })
public class PasswordResetControllerTest {

    @Autowired 
    private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    ...

    @Before  
    public void init() {  
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.applicationContext).build();
    }
}
```

now it's work like a charm

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

you are doing a slice test to test the controller alone in that case you dont need below configuration @ContextConfiguration(classes = { Application.class })

Try :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional
@WebMvcTest(PasswordResetController.class)
public class PasswordResetControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void getPasswordForgetView() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(get("/password/forget"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need the whole application (multi databases) at a later point in time, that's why I have the contextconfiguration declared.

Comment: @ManuZi you need to decide which one you're doing in this class, doing a web slice test and having full contextconfiguration are contradicting each other.